# php remove tags before a specified tag

Tags: php, html, dom

I want to remove all image-tags before the headline starts, but they are not nested the same way. And then remove the empty tags.

```
<div class="c2">
  <img src="image/file" width="480" height="360" alt="Image" />
</div>
<div class="c2">
  <div class="headline">
    headline
  </div>
  <div class="headline">
    headline2
  </div>
</div>
```

and different nested tags like

```
<div class="c2">
  <p>
    <img src="image/A.JPG" width="480" height="319" alt="Image" />
  </p>
  <div class="headline">
    A headline
  </div>
</div>
```

i think that could be solved recursively, but i dont know how.

Thanks for your help!

Comment: You want to do this with PHP? To parse the HTML file and remove elements?

Comment: Yes, i tried simple php, but no succes.

Comment: I hate to be that person, but this would be much easier with jQuery...

Comment: @user1768700 can you show what you tried?

Comment: @EmmyS I'm not sure about that. It doesn't have to be very complicated if you use [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php). It does require that valid html is created and that the html is buffered on the server.

Answer (score 0):

**EDIT**: if you want to remove only `<img>` followed by `<div><div class="headline>"` or `<div class="headline">`, use this xpath:

```
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img[../following-sibling::div[1]/div/@class='headline' or ../following-sibling::div[1]/@class='headline']");
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/QhprLP

Do it like this:

```
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadHTML($x); // assuming HTML in $x
$xpath = new DOMXpath($doc);
$imgs = $xpath->query("//img"); // select all <img> nodes

foreach ($imgs as $img) { // loop through list of all <img> nodes
$parent = $img->parentNode; 
$parent->removeChild($img); // delete <img> node
if ($parent->childNodes->length >= 1) // if parent node of <img> is empty delete it
        $parent->parentNode->removeChild($parent);
}

echo htmlentities($doc->saveHTML()); // display the new HTML
```

see it working: http://codepad.viper-7.com/350Hw6

Comment: Thanks for your answers, but i want to keep all images after the healine.